# URL 指定での Web ページ表示時にリダイレクトされるのを停止したい

Tags: html, css

以下の構文、サンプルページのとおり、URL を指定して表示させる HTML を書いたのですが、当該 URL を表示後、当該 URL 側の挙動として自動的に別の URL にリダイレクトされてしまいます。（この例ですと、「https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/map.html#5&contents=earthquake_map」を指定していますが、「https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/map.html#10/32.75/131.616/&5&elem=int&contents=earthquake_map」にリダイレクトされてしまいます。（縮尺が変わってしまいます。）
このリダイレクトをやめて、最初に指定した「https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/map.html#5&contents=earthquake_map」が表示されるようにできませんでしょうか？
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

＜構文＞

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#center{
background-color: transparent;
margin-top:-525px;
margin-left:-30px;
}
-->
</style>
<html>
<body>
<div style="no-repeat 0% 0%">
</div>
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" width="1500" height="2000" src="https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/map.html#5&contents=earthquake_map" scrolling="no" id="center"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("location.reload(false)",15000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

＜サンプルページ＞
http://blngs.net/tsunami_kisyoucyou_shindo.htm

Comment: サイトのリダイレクトについては、サイトの仕様によるところが大きいです。とくに震度情報となると紐づく地震情報に基づいて縮尺を決めている可能性が高く、オープンなQAで聞くよりも直接問い合わせしたほうが早いかもしれないです。やりたいこととしてはどんな震度情報であっても日本全体を表示したいということですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！おっしゃるとおり、url内の#5として指定している日本全国を表示したい、という主旨になります！
sandbox構文を入れて色々試したのですが、設定がまずかったのかリダイレクトを止める事ができずにおります。
その他、一瞬表示されてはいるのでその内容をキャプチャして表示するとか、ウルトラC的などんな方法でも結構ですので何か手段がありますでしょうか…。
お手数をおかけしますがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 正確には、リダイレクトではなく [`History.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)によるURLの書き換えですね。`map.html` に埋め込まれているJavaScriptで実行しているのだと思われます。(ズーム処理も、同じく埋め込まれたJSで実行していると思われます)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。iframe内のsandbox構文やその他のテクニックで当該Javascriptの挙動を停止するやり方はないものでしょうか？あるいは書き換え前のページをどこかに確保しておくなど…画像ベースでのスクリーンショットでも問題ありません。どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 0):

技術的な回答ではありませんし、[マルチポスト先の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/327137) でも同様の指摘が既に付いていますが、気になる部分がいくつかあるのでこちらでも投稿しておきます。

---

今回 `iframe` で呼び出しているのは「気象庁のサイト」であり、あなたが提示したサンプルページとは別ドメイン = 管理者もあなたではない、と見受けられます。

サイトがどのように表示されるかはサイト管理者の範疇であり、部外者のあなたが勝手にコントロールできないし、すべきではないと思います。

もう1点、著作権に関する懸念もあります。

該当の地図ページのヘッダにあるヘルプをクリックすると、以下のような表示がされます。

> 本製品を複製する場合には、国土地理院の長の承認を得なければならない。

`iframe` での呼び出しが "複製" となるかは微妙なところですが、[利用マニュアル](https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/manual/) を見てもこのような呼び出しについて明言されていません。(禁止されていないから自由に使ってOK、とはなりません)

[あなたの別の投稿でのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74602/%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a6%e3%82%b6%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e6%99%82%e3%81%ae%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%81%bf%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e3%83%ac%e3%82%b9%e5%8c%96%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e7%8f%be%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99#comment83189_74602) では「15秒おきに自動更新するつもり」とも書かれていますが、相手先に負担をかける行為となる可能性があるので、許可された使い方なのかを十分に確認することをお勧めします。

**参考:**

[無断リンク - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%84%A1%E6%96%AD%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF)

> ### 類似のリンク問題
>
> #### 直リンク
>
> `<iframe>` タグを使用して、被リンク側サイトのHTML文書を自サイトの一部であるかのように見せかけるような行為が問題視されている。このような場合、リンク元のページを表示するたびにリンク先のサーバの資源を使用することになるほか、リンク元のページの一部として表示されるため著作権法上の問題が発生する可能性がある。