# ブラウザ更新時の読み込みシームレス化を実現したいです

Tags: html, css

ブラウザ更新時の画像読み込みシームレス化(以下のブラウザページ）のページ全体版を実現したいと思っています。
https://teratail.com/questions/271650

上の過去の質問回答の構文では画像URLを指定していますが、画像URLではなくWEBページ全体を表示させる場合に更新時のラグ（ページが完全に表示されるまでの読み込み中の状態）をなくしシームレスに表示が切り替わるようにしたいと思っています。

現在の構文及びサンプルページは以下になりますが、一番上の既存の質問の回答を活用してもいいですし、以下の構文を修正して実現する方法でもいいのですが、教えていただけると助かります！
ちなみに＜サンプルページ＞を見ていただくとわかるのですが、ＷＥＢページの読み込み以外に、サイト側の「読み込み中・・・」の表示も出ないようにしたいと思っています。

ずっと悩み続けているので、この機会に改善したいと思っています。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

＜構文＞

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#center{
background-color: transparent;
margin-top:-260px;
margin-left:-70px;
}
-->
</style>
<html>
<body>
<div style="background: url(no_tsunami1.png) no-repeat 0% 0%">
</div>
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" width="1000" height="1000" src="https://www.jma.go.jp/jp/tsunami/" scrolling="no" id="center"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("location.reload(false)",15000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

＜サンプルページ＞
http://blngs.net/tsunami_kisyoucyou.htm

Comment: 通常のWebページの遷移の場合必ずラグが発生します。白い画面や前の画面のままでブラウザタブやURLバーにぐるぐるが発生します。これらをなくしたいということですか？

Comment: はい、おっしゃるとおりです！
なくしたいというより、最終表示物が読み込まれるまで待って、最後に最終表示物だけを表示(直前の更新前のものと差し替え)したいという事となります。
こちらも何かウルトラC的なアイデアがありましたら教えていただきたいです。
どうぞ宜しくお願いします。

Comment: なぜなくしたいのでしょうか？仮に数秒かかるような処理だった場合、操作したのに画面が変わらず、読み込み中も表示されなくなると、ユーザビリティ的にはあれなんだ！？ってなりませんか？読み込み中って表示があるだけで操作して待ちの時間が持てることになりませんか？

Comment: 説明足らずですみません。このhtml ページは15秒ごとに自動更新されるようにしているのでユーザーが操作するような事は想定しておらず、その15秒毎の自動更新時に毎回更新中の状態が表示されると煩わしいため何とか出来ないかと考えております。